# displaying two controls on the same line

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to display two controls on same line. Right now, one control is slightly upper than other control. I am using bootstrap to display the control. below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="AuditDetails" class="control-label"></label>
            <select id="ddlAuditDetails" asp-for="AuditDetails" class="form-control">
                <option value="4">--Type of Record--</option>
                <option value="txnNum">Transaction Number</option>
                <option value="custNum">Customer Number</option>
                <option value="doc">Fetch by Uploading File</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="TypeOfRecord" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-6" id="dvUpload" style="display:none; >
       
        @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Async(a => a
        .Save("Async_Save", "Audit")
        .Remove("Async_Remove", "Audit")
        .AutoUpload(true)
        
        )
        )
        </div>
    </div>
```

Right now, the above code shows both the controls like this:

[image]

As you can see the kendo control is slightly above than select control. I want both the controls on the same line. I tried putting style:

```
style="display:none;display:flex;flex-direction:column"
```

in this div tag

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="dvUpload" >
```

That didn't work. kendo control is still slightly above the drop down control. How can I put both the controls on the same line. This is the rendered HTML on the source:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="AuditDetails">Select One of the option</label>
            <select id="ddlAuditDetails" class="form-control" name="AuditDetails">
                <option value="4">--Type of Record--</option>
                <option value="txnNum">Transaction Number</option>
                <option value="custNum">Customer Number</option>
                <option value="docHash">Uploading File</option>
            </select>
            
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" id="dvTransactionNumber" style="display: none;">
        <label class="control-label" for="TransactionNumber">Transaction Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="TransactionNumber" name="TransactionNumber" value="" />
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TransactionNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="dvCustNumber" style="display: none;">
        <label class="control-label" for="CustNumber">Customer Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CustNumber" name="CustNumber" value="" />
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CustNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" id="dvUpload" style="display:none;display:flex;flex-direction:column">
       
        <input id="files" name="files" type="file" /><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#files").kendoUpload({"async":{"autoUpload":true,"saveUrl":"/Auditing/Async_Save","removeUrl":"/Auditing/Async_Remove"}});});</script>
        

        </div>

         
   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the utility classes from Bootstrap: `mt-1`, `mt-2`.
However, if in later stages of development if the font size or something else changes, you would have to come back here and adjust the margin.

If you want the exact same space that the other control labels are taking up, just add an invisible label above the control and use the Bootstrap utility class `invisible` to make it invisible.

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="dvUpload" style="display:none;">
   <label class="control-label invisible" for="files">File upload</label>
   <!-- The above label will stay invisible, while also consuming space just like the other labels -->

    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .Async(a => a
    .Save("Async_Save", "Audit")
    .Remove("Async_Remove", "Audit")
    .AutoUpload(true)
    
    )
    )
    </div>
```

So the rendered HTML would look somewhat like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" id="dvUpload" style="display:none;display:flex;flex-direction:column">
   <label class="control-label invisible" for="files">File upload</label>
   <!-- The above label will stay invisible, while also consuming space just like the other labels -->
   <input id="files" name="files" type="file" /><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#files").kendoUpload({"async":{"autoUpload":true,"saveUrl":"/Auditing/Async_Save","removeUrl":"/Auditing/Async_Remove"}});});</script>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add Margin Top.

```
mt-1 or mt-2
```

You can increase, decrease the margin top